# Piecewise Function Definition

Tags: piecewise

I am new to Mathematica, and I am unsure on how to do this.

I am working with piecewise function

$$
    f_N(x) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if}\;\;x = j\sqrt{3}, \quad j=1,...,N \\
    0 & \text{otherwise},\end{cases}
$$

for some arbitrary $N$ that I define when I call the function.

I understand that I have to use the built in function `Piecewise` to be able to perform this, but am not sure how to include the fact that $N$ is a variable and not have to define the function again and again for every use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[n_, x_] := Piecewise[{
   {1, (Sqrt[3] <= x <= n Sqrt[3]) && Mod[x, Sqrt[3]] == 0}
   }, 0]
```

Comment: Note in this answer I've avoided using `IntegerQ` and Q-functions because those won't work as expected with symbolic arguments as they must evaluate to True/False.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that works perfectly